# Data frame math in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that is structured like this with 3 levels of index :

```
                        a    b
    0hr    0.01um   0   12   42
                    1   10   35
           0.1um    0   8    28
                    1   6    21
          Control   0   4    14
                    1   2    7
   24hr    0.01um   0   18   30
                    1   15   25
           0.1um    0   12   20
                    1   9    15
          Control   0   6    10
                    1   3    5
```

The DataFrame was imported from a series of excel files.  Sorry I can't provide a piece of code to generate this 3 level deep index structure because I don't know how to generate it directly.

I'm looking for the syntax to divide every value by its respective "Control".

For example

```
                        a       b
    0hr    0.01um   0   =12/4   =42/14
                    1   =10/2   =35/7
           0.1um    0   =8/4    =28/14
                    1   =6/2    =21/7
          Control   0   =4/4    =14/14
                    1   =2/2    =7/7
   24hr    0.01um   0   =18/6   =30/10
                    1   =15/3   =25/5
           0.1um    0   =12/6   =20/10
                    1   =9/3    =15/5
          Control   0   =6/6    =10/10
                    1   =3/3    =5/5
```

which would yield a data frame with these values :

```
                        a    b
    0hr    0.01um   0   3    3
                    1   5    5
           0.1um    0   2    2
                    1   3    3
          Control   0   1    1
                    1   1    1
   24hr    0.01um   0   3    3
                    1   5    5
           0.1um    0   2    2
                    1   3    3
          Control   0   1    1
                    1   1    1
```

I tried to do this with a loop but I think there might be better syntax with the DataFrame.div method, but I can't quite figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "to divide the "Control" level index by every value contained in that first level index's second level" this is confusing (to me), would be good to show the desired result in this example. Edit: It's not clear to me where the numbers e.g. 4 and 2 come from. *ps. one way to create pasteable code for a multiindex DataFrame is to use `reset_index()`, show that then `set_index()`.*

Comment: The "for example" section shows what I'm trying to achieve as a formula.  E.g. =3/3 would result in 1

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your question has nothing to do with the strings.  You want to divide each number by the respective Control number per your example.  If I'm correct, I would omit the strings from your questions as I think it's causing some confusion

Comment: Bob, yes.  I also think it may be adding confusion.  I will revise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would expect to be able to just define the control and use it to divide the database, but unfortunately this does not work as expected.  It only divides where the index lines up (on 'Control'), leaving NaNs on the other index levels.

```
# Initialize DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {('0hr', '0.01um', 0): 12,
  ('0hr', '0.01um', 1): 10,
  ('0hr', '0.1um', 0): 8,
  ('0hr', '0.1um', 1): 6,
  ('0hr', 'Control', 0): 4,
  ('0hr', 'Control', 1): 2,
  ('24hr', '0.01um', 0): 18,
  ('24hr', '0.01um', 1): 15,
  ('24hr', '0.1um', 0): 12,
  ('24hr', '0.1um', 1): 9,
  ('24hr', 'Control', 0): 6,
  ('24hr', 'Control', 1): 3},
 'b': {('0hr', '0.01um', 0): 42,
  ('0hr', '0.01um', 1): 35,
  ('0hr', '0.1um', 0): 28,
  ('0hr', '0.1um', 1): 21,
  ('0hr', 'Control', 0): 14,
  ('0hr', 'Control', 1): 7,
  ('24hr', '0.01um', 0): 30,
  ('24hr', '0.01um', 1): 25,
  ('24hr', '0.1um', 0): 20,
  ('24hr', '0.1um', 1): 15,
  ('24hr', 'Control', 0): 10,
  ('24hr', 'Control', 1): 5}})

control = df.xs('Control', level=1)

>>> control 
                a   b
0hr  Control 0  4  14
             1  2   7
24hr Control 0  6  10
             1  3   5

>>> df.divide(control) 
                 a   b
0hr  0.01um  0 NaN NaN
             1 NaN NaN
     0.1um   0 NaN NaN
             1 NaN NaN
     Control 0   1   1
             1   1   1
24hr 0.01um  0 NaN NaN
             1 NaN NaN
     0.1um   0 NaN NaN
             1 NaN NaN
     Control 0   1   1
             1   1   1
```

Alternatively, one can try to specify the level when doing the division.  The problem with this approach, however, is that this operation will raise an error because both operands are still MultiIndex objects. An error is thrown because there could potentially be ambiguity if the levels could match in multiple ways.

```
>>> df.divide(control, level=1)
TypeError: Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous
```

The trick is to reshape your DataFrame to avoid this ambiguity.

```
# Reshape DataFrame.
df2 = df.T.stack(level=[0, 1])
>>> df2
          0.01um  0.1um  Control
a 0hr  0      12      8        4
       1      10      6        2
  24hr 0      18     12        6
       1      15      9        3
b 0hr  0      42     28       14
       1      35     21        7
  24hr 0      30     20       10
       1      25     15        5


# Divide reshaped DataFrame by 'Control' on the appropriate axis.
df3 = df2.divide(df2.Control, axis=0)
>>> df3
          0.01um  0.1um  Control
a 0hr  0       3      2        1
       1       5      3        1
  24hr 0       3      2        1
       1       5      3        1
b 0hr  0       3      2        1
       1       5      3        1
  24hr 0       3      2        1
       1       5      3        1
```

You then need to reshape the DataFrame back to its original form.

```
# Shape DataFrame back to original order.
result = df3.T.unstack().reorder_levels([1, 3, 2, 0]).unstack()

>>> result
                a  b
0hr  0.01um  0  3  3
             1  5  5
     0.1um   0  2  2
             1  3  3
     Control 0  1  1
             1  1  1
24hr 0.01um  0  3  3
             1  5  5
     0.1um   0  2  2
             1  3  3
     Control 0  1  1
             1  1  1
```

Comment: very interesting approach.  I'm having some trouble running your code though.  First issue is that you've created df as a dict not as a DataFrame.  Easy to fix.  The second is that df2 = df.T.stack(level=[0, 1]) doesn't seem to place Control in a column as you've shown.  The line that creates df3 then fails with 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Control'  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the confusion with the df assignment.  I've made a correction in my response.  The rest of the steps, however, show exactly as were posted originally (Pandas 0.14.1, Python 2.7.9).

Comment: Interesting ... I'm using pandas 0.16.0 and python 2.7.9 and get a different result from df2 = df.T.stack(level=[0, 1]) than you show.  df2 = df.T.stack(level=[0, 2]) produces your result.  Interestingly the rest of the example works but then when I try to use the same strategy in my real code it doesn't.  
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (684,) (228,) 

print df2.shape shows (228, 3)
print df2.Control.shape shows (228,)

I'll try grabbing pandas 0.14.1

Comment: Yes, I can replicate your results with pandas 0.16.0, and yes, you need level=[0,2] (strange...).

Comment: df3 = df2.divide(df2.Control, axis=0)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (684,) (228,) 

df2 and df3 are both 228 rows though.

Comment: And downgrading to pandas 0.14.1 breaks other parts of my script :-/

Comment: print(df2.shape) = (228, 3) 
print(df2.Control.shape) = (228,)

Comment: I'm confused doesn't df3 = df2.divide(df2.Control, axis=0) call the column named control in df2?  It doesn't call the control variable, correct?

Comment: You are correct. Try: df3 = df2.divide(df2.Control.values, axis=0). If that fails, post a link to your anonymized data (i.e. use random numbers, but keep the data structure) and I can tinker with it.

Comment: I have no idea what I did but in the process of cleaning up the code this started working.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's what I got.  More steps than I like, but it works.  Hopefully someone comes up with something better

Starting with your frame

```
                a   b
0hr 0.01um  0   12  42
            1   10  35
    0.1um   0   8   28
            1   6   21
   Control  0   4   14
            1   2   7
24hr 0.01um 0   18  30
            1   15  25
     0.1um  0   12  20
            1   9   15
    Control 0   6   10
            1   3   5
```

First we reset the index. Note the column names of the former index.  Your's might be different.

```
frame.reset_index(inplace=True)
frame

    level_0 level_1 level_2 a   b
0   0hr     0.01um  0      12   42
1   0hr     0.01um  1      10   35
2   0hr     0.1um   0      8    28
3   0hr     0.1um   1      6    21
4   0hr     Control 0      4    14
5   0hr     Control 1      2    7
6   24hr    0.01um  0     18    30
7   24hr    0.01um  1     15    25
8   24hr    0.1um   0     12    20
9   24hr    0.1um   1      9    15
10  24hr    Control 0      6    10
11  24hr    Control 1      3    5
```

Next we filter for everything marked as Control using boolean indexing.  Then we [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the 'filtered' version with our original.

```
  filter = frame["level_1"] == "Control"
  frame = pd.merge(frame,frame[filter],on=["level_0","level_2"],suffixes=["","_control"])
  frame

    level_0 level_1 level_2 a   b   level_1_control a_control   b_control
0   0hr     0.01um  0      12   42  Control         4          14
1   0hr     0.1um   0      8    28  Control         4          14
2   0hr     Control 0      4    14  Control         4          14
3   0hr     0.01um  1      10   35  Control         2          7
4   0hr     0.1um   1      6    21  Control         2          7
5   0hr     Control 1      2    7   Control         2          7
6   24hr    0.01um  0     18    30  Control         6          10
7   24hr    0.1um   0     12    20  Control         6          10
8   24hr    Control 0     6     10  Control         6          10
9   24hr    0.01um  1     15    25  Control         3          5
10  24hr    0.1um   1      9    15  Control         3          5
11  24hr    Control 1      3    5   Control         3          5
```

and now the division..  finally..  Lot going on in that last line.  Slimming down the data frame, sorting and re-applying the index to match the original frame

```
frame["a"] = frame["a"] / frame["a_control"]
frame["b"] = frame["b"] / frame["b_control"]
frame = frame[["level_0","level_1","level_2","a","b"]].sort(["level_0","level_1","level_2"]).set_index(["level_0","level_1","level_2"])
frame

                         a  b
level_0 level_1 level_2     
0hr     0.01um  0        3  3
                1        5  5
        0.1um   0        2  2
                1        3  3
        Control 0        1  1
                1        1  1
24hr    0.01um  0        3  3
                1        5  5
        0.1um   0        2  2
                1        3  3
        Control 0        1  1
                1        1  1
```

Comment: Is there any way to make this solution more generic as there are many columns.  Calling each one as you do here with a and b is not really practical.